# What is a "lumpy business"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, word-meaning

I ran into a sentence from a [Fortune article](http://fortune.com/2018/02/06/data-sheet-apple-google-stock-market/).

> The point is that services are smoothing out an otherwise **"lumpy business"**.

As the [Oxford Dictionaries' definition](https://en.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/lumpy) of the adjective *lumpy* goes:

> 1 Full of or covered with lumps.
>
> 1.1 Nautical (of water) formed by the wind into small waves.

Neither really fits the sentence, nor in my opinion does Merriam Webster's additional usage *having a heavy clumsy appearance*. It seems to me *bumpy* would be a better word to collocate with *business*. What is a **lumpy business**?

Comment: It's just a slightly metaphorical use of *lumpy* - the business is not smooth and even, but has bumps and irregularities.

Comment: You really should post the entire sentence: ***The point is that services are smoothing out an otherwise lumpy business***. This is a typical metaphor: you smooth out the bed cover when what's under it is lumpy. You smooth out dough [when making cake or bread], when it is lumpy. You smooth out the lumps in wet cement before it dries. You smooth out the earth if it is lumpy when you plant plants. Most business writing in sophisticated business publications are full of metaphors.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the business world, lumpiness refers to revenues that come in big chunks at irregular intervals as opposed to in steady, consistent increments. I would not call this usage metaphorical, though it is certainly jargony.

Say you're a company that builds custom-ordered houses that each cost millions of dollars. Maybe you only sell 10 homes per year. In that case, your revenues are going to be pretty lumpy. You could try to tell your investors that you expect such and such an increase in year-over-year revenue for the upcoming quarter, but if one of your houses gets finished a week behind schedule and falls into the next fiscal quarter, you may end up coming considerably short of your projections for the current quarter and then considerably exceeding (previous) expectations for the next quarter on a percentage basis.

Contrast that against against the business model of the bank that your customers are using to get loans to buy your houses. Those banks give each customer a loan (a mortgage) and then sit back and collect the same payment on the same day of the month for years and years. It's the exact opposite of a lumpy revenue stream.

The article you're referring to talks about Apple and its increasing revenues from services.

The context is that Apple's sales are typically pretty lumpy because they will release a new product (most notably, a new version of the iPhone once a year); lots of people will go to buy that product on its release, generating billions of dollars for the company in the first couple months after the product release; and then sales will fall off until the next product is released. But with increasing revenue from ongoing sources like App Store purchases (which people make all year long) and subscriptions to Apple Music (which customers pay on a monthly basis), the company's revenues are smoothing out a bit because a larger percentage of those revenues are coming from reliable sources that are not as dependent on whether or not the company's latest product was a big hit. That means the company can be more confident in exactly how much money it'll have coming in for any given month or quarter or year.